# Using Image as a Border of website

Tags: html, css

I am creating a website for a Media Agency and I need to insert a Frame-type border on the website. The website should look like a it is placed in Television. 
Television Image is a PNG with outer stuff and the inner part in transparent.

My website is at [www.mediamantra.co/demo](http://mediamantra.co/demo)
and I want the website to actually look like  :
[image: This is the actual image that I want my website to look like]

I think there is a z-index CSS property but it isn't useful. I would appreciate any suggestions and guidance.

Comment: What is the tv image url?

Comment: I just dropped the Idea of TV and currently made some changes in the website. Now I think it looks great.
Anyways, Thanks a ton for your time and interest!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its looking nice..!! 
why you need to do such things?

Anyways, you can use a `.png` image to overlay the website and give your body a border to get spaces around four sides, like

```
body:before, body:after {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    background: #00;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 10px; //according to your image
}
body:before {
    top: 0;
}
body:after {
    bottom: 0;
}
body {
    border-left: 10px solid #900; //according to your image
    border-right: 10px solid #900;  //according to your image
}
```

Comment: first of all thanks for your time and the client is demanding the television that's why I am putting it, however, but I want to use that television image above my website, I don't need borders.Actually I want the Television screen to display my website.
In a way that it looks that the complete website is inserted in the TV. Hope u understand my point. Thanks!

Comment: yeah, I understand, I said to overlay tv image and make it position fixed and the borders on body to give spaces on the four sides of the website so that it appears to be in tv.

Comment: Thanks buddy, I actually dropped the idea of using that TV and now I made a few changes to make it look better. Thanks for your time bro!